# What's a good selective pressure to use in tournament selection in a genetic algorithm?

Tags: genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

What is the optimal and usual value of selective pressure in tournament selection? What percent of the best members of the current generation should propagate to the next generation?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there isn't a great answer to this question. The optimal parameters will vary from problem to problem, and people use a wide range of them. Selecting the right tournament selection parameters is currently more of an art than a science. Stronger selective pressure (a larger tournament) will generally result in the population converging on a solution faster, at the cost of that solution potentially not being as good. This is called the exploration vs. exploitation tradeoff, and it underlies most algorithms for searching a large space of possible solutions - you're not going to get away from it.

I know that's not very helpful, though - you want a starting place, and that's completely reasonable. So here's the best one I know of (and I know a number of others who use it as a go-to default tournament configuration as well): a tournament size of two. Basically, this means you just keep picking random pairs of solutions, choosing the best one, and sending it to the next generation (with mutation and crossover as desired), until the next generation is the desired size. This has the nice property that any member of the population besides the absolute worst has a chance of getting to the next generation, but better ones have a better chance.